# Trying to pass data from a .php file to a .js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm trying to build a website which has a video section. The problem that i've encountered is that in order to change the video in the '.video-player' i need to pass  data(the name of the video) which is inside a database  from my index.php file to my scriptz.js file.

What i've tried so far is to echo that data in a div and retrieve it using document.getElementbyId in javascript which doesn't seem to work. Here is the code

INDEX.php

```
<ul class="video-list">
<?php
while($videotemp=mysql_fetch_array($ris))
{
?>
    <li class="video-element">
        <div class="image-duration">
            <img class="video-thumbnails" src="images/<?php echo $videotemp["thumbnails"] ;?>"/>
            <p class="duration"><?php echo number_format($videotemp["duration"]/100,0);?>:<?php echo $duration2=$videotemp["duration"]%100; ?></p>
        </div>
        <p class="video-title"><?php echo $videotemp["author"];?> - <?php echo $videotemp["name"] ;?></p>
        <div id="source"><?php echo $videotemp["source"]  ?></div>
    </li>
<?php   
}
?>
</ul>

<video id="video-player"  preload="auto" data-setup="{}"  controls  >
    <source id="mp4" src="" type="video/mp4" />
    <source id="ogv" src="" type="video/ogv" />
    <source id="webm" src="" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Cese.css

```
#source{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Scriptz.js

```
$('.video-element').click(function(){
        var $videosource=document.getElementById("source");

            document.getElementById('mp4').setAttribute('src','videos/'+$videosource + ".mp4");
            document.getElementById('ogv').setAttribute('src','videos/'+$videosource + ".ogv");
            document.getElementById('webm').setAttribute('src','videos/'+$videosource + ".webm");
            $("#video-box")[0].load();

    });
```

Up to any suggestions , thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see the `<div id="source"><?php echo $videotemp["source"]  ?></div>`? Is there the source name inside the div?

Comment: no i can't see the div because it's hidden by the css . inside the div should be the name of the video

Comment: I meant in the web inspector tool. Can you see that the information is inside of the div to confirm. Then I would have said what VSnakd said. Try to confirm that the echo fills the div with your web tools.

Comment: Ah my bad didn't get it at first, yes it does show using the web inspector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add innerHTML.

You want the string inside the ID not the ID itself.

So : var $videosource=document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;

Comment: That is what I was thinking too. The only reason it isn't working is because he is just getting the element, not the text of the element.

Comment: Hey thanks for such a quick answer, i've tried adding .innerHTML but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Although what you're saying makes perfect sense so i'm leaving it there.

Comment: ok i've finally managed to make it work although i had to use html() because of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a look at [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

You can use these with [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as shown below:

You can create a PHP page and format it as JSON to then return the data you need for the video.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ianjamieson/dcz4jed3/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-videoId]').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json/', // this would be your data.php page
      data: { // this is like adding ?videoId=1234 to data.php
        videoId: $(this).data('videoId')
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        // json will now contain your video information
        console.log(json);
      }
    });
  });
});


/*
    data.php would need to use PHP function:
  json_encode($phpArray);
*/
```

Comment: May have mis interpreted the question, but I suppose this answer is still valid for reference.

Comment: gonna look into ajax and come back with a feedback